# Passwords must not contain the user's account name or parts of the user's full name that exceed three consecutive characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, passwords, password-policy

I need to develop in a .NET Application using SQL Server Stored Procedures a validation for passwords.

I've already developed the first validations (uppercase,lowercase,number,etc) but now i need to check that the **Passwords must not contain the user's account name or parts of the user's full name that exceed three consecutive characters** but i don't know how to do this in SQL (in a stored procedure), maybe with regular expression?

I have searched since this is usually very typical in password validation, but I have not found anything in SQL Server

any ideas about this?

Thanks & Regards!

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in SQL at all, doing it in SQL means you have passed the password unencrypted to the RDBMS and that means it's as good as compromised. All this logic *must* be in the application layer.

Comment: Should I do then in the .NET code? in my case c #.
I also need to check that it is not the password that it has been used the last 6 times. Maybe I should get those passwords (saved encrypted) and decrypt them in the application and do all the validations there? Thanks!

Comment: If you can decrypt the password you also have a problem. If you need to have a history, store the historical salts and hashes, and then compare the new password hash to the old hash history.

Comment: You are right, I should only compare if the encrypted password is the same that I have in the history also encrypted

Comment: "has not been used the last 6 times" is a completely bogus and useless requirement. That just pushes people to use values like "password1", "password2", "password3", etc. This does NOT improve security.

Comment: First of all sending critical data unencrypted to the server is not a good idea. Your data must me unencrypted on the assumption that you are performing validations on the server rather than the client through stored procedures. Second if you still want that then use regular expressions for validataion. Third you will have to log all the old passwords in the database. then check latest 6 if match then send message else change the password.

Comment: To do in .Net code you should hash the password and then fetch the hashed password from the server and compare. Log all the hashed passwords in the database. Fetch last 6 passwords and compare with the hashed password ( of course trying all the salts in old passwords as different salts give different results ) entered. If match warn else store password.

Answer (score 0):

That is defiantly not the right password protection.
First of all sending critical data unencrypted to the server is not a good idea. Your data must me unencrypted on the assumption that you are performing validations on the server rather than the client through stored procedures. Second if you still want that then use regular expressions for validataion. Third you will have to log all the old passwords in the database. then check latest 6 if match then send message else change the password.

Rather what you should do is :
To do in .Net code you should hash the password and then fetch the hashed password from the server and compare. Log all the hashed passwords in the database. Fetch last 6 passwords and compare with the hashed password ( of course trying all the salts in old passwords as different salts give different results ) entered. If match warn else store password.